# Help with an induction proof

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Here's the thing I'm trying to prove

$2^k - (2^{k-1} + 2^{k-2} + ... + 2^2 + 2^1) = 2$

It's obviously easy for the k = 1 case, but I'm stuck on the k + 1 case.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Note that

\begin{align}
2^{k + 1} - \left(2^k + 2^{k - 1} + ... + 2^2 + 2^1\right) &= 2^{k} + 2^k - \left(2^k + 2^{k - 1} + ... + 2^2 + 2^1\right) \\ &= 2^k - \left(2^{k - 1} + ... + 2^1\right)\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need induction.  Rewrite your expression as $2^k - 2(1 + 2 + ... + 2^{k-2})$.  The sum is the parens is a standard geometric series.  If you will write down that sum, the proof will be staring at you.